# XSD complex type is null but simple type inside can't be empty

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, null, is-empty

I'm looking for the best way to ensure no error is thrown when you have the following situation:

I have a simple type phone number validated by the XSD in the following way:

```
<xs: simpleType name="phone-number">
<xs:restriction Base="xs:token">
<xs:pattern value="\d{9}"/>
</xs:restriction>
<xs:SimpleType>
```

The pattern doesn't allow for empty values, only 9 digit values.

Now I have a complexType person-data that has an element of type phone-number inside.

```
<xs:complexType name="person-data">
        <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="phone-number" type="phone-number" minOccurs="0"/>
```

what is the best way to ensure that validation passes (or doesn't validate at all) with empty values?

The problem appears when the XML file doesn't contain the person-data tag (take it its null) - then the validation fails on the phone-number type

Comment: Where in the world uses 9-digit phone numbers, as a matter of interest?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "what is the best way to ensure that validation passes (or doesn't validate at all) with empty values?".If the person-data element is absent, then the bits of the schema you have shown us are irrelevant, because they only affect what happens when it's present. Are you saying you want a person-data element to be allowed to contain a phone-number element that has empty content?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xs:pattern value="\d{9}"/>
```

to

```
<xs:pattern value="\d{9}|"/>
```

to allow 9-digit numbers or the empty string.

Note also that XML and XSD are case-sensitive, so you'll have to make several additional changes to your definition of `phone-number`:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="phone-number">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{9}|"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

The above definition is syntactically correct and will allow tokens consisting of 9 digits or no characters.

Final note:  `xs:token` will allow leading and trailing spaces; use `xs:string` if you do not want those.